# Swift Screen time Api error (family controls error code=2 )

Tags: swift

I'm try to physical device always getting error on Error for Family Controls: Error Domain=FamilyControls.FamilyControlsError Code=2 "(null)"

```
AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization { result in                  
    switch result {        
        case .success():           
            break         
        case .failure(let error):           
           print("Error for Family Controls: (error)") 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this link at [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682257)
it says:

> Requesting FamilyControls authorization on Simulator is supported by the ScreenTime API.
> FamilyControlsError Code=2 is the error code for an invalid account type; this is expected when trying to authorize FamilyControls on a non-child iCloud account.
> FamilyControlsError Code=3 is an internal error, which isn't expected.

I hope it'll help you. Have a nice day mate !

Comment: Using shared authorization I am able to authorize the child's device and able to see all the installed apps on the child's mobile on the parent device. But when I am trying to call DeviceActivity nothing happens.  This is how I am calling DeviceActivity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777982/unable-to-call-device-activity-in-screen-time-api-from-parent-device

Comment: @AnishLal can you please guide me to authorize the child's device? I am using same code but unfortunately I am getting FamilyControlError Code=0. I am executing this code on iPad v15.7 with child iCloud account logged in on iPad. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: @sam did you find your mistake by any chance? I am also receiving an error code 0

Answer (score 1):

The method to get autherization is an async:

```
func requestAuthorization(for member: FamilyControlsMember) async throws
```

So try something like this~

```
Task {
        do {

            try await AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: .individual)

        } catch {
           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, here is how I solved it.

ScreenTime API is a "PAID" API, which means that only accounts under the ADP (Apple Developer Program) can use it. You can double check it in their official source: [Supported capabilities (iOS)](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/reference/supported-capabilities-ios/)

Once you make sure your developer account is under the ADP membership you only have to sign it in your project. Select your project -> Signing & Capabilities -> select your account on "team".

This will solve error code = 2.

If you get error code = 3 you basically need to build your project in a real device and not on the simulator.

Hope it helps :)